# Expression register and fractions

Tags: arithmetic, expression-register

I tried to use the arithmetic register with a fraction (7/8) and it returned 0! How do I exert better control over the register so that it gives me what I want?

The literal sequence I used, while in insert mode: `<C-R>=(7/8)<enter>` result: `0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As none of your numbers contains a decimal point ([`:help floating-point-format`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#floating-point-format)), Vim treats the expression as *integer division*, and also gives an integer result.

Simply specify one or both numbers as floats, and you'll get the expected result: `<C-R>=7.0/8<CR>` gives `0.875`.

For more control (number of digits, precision, padding), use [`printf()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#printf%28%29) with the corresponding format specifications.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried `=(7./8)` suspecting I had to force vim to recognize it as a float but didn't get as far as trying `.0` before giving up. Appreciate your answer and thanks for the reference to the relevant help page (which I also couldn't find on my own).

Comment: Glad I could help! Vim's syntax is a bit unintuitive there, as float support had to be introduced into the existing syntax to avoid breaking backwards compatibility, especially in the area of string concatenation via `.`.